# css second level dropdowns disappearing

Tags: html, css, dropdown

My issue is the Html/Css dropdown second level disappears ans I move the cursor, currently works fine on Safari on Iphone but no other browsers I have tried.

Seems to be something to do with the width in the CSS, if I set a fixed px value all seems to fuction but then it does not reize correctly for all screens.

All parameters are % based througout the site and so far that is working fine cross platform.

```css
.third-level-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

.third-level-menu>li {
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
}

.third-level-menu>li:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

.second-level-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

.second-level-menu>li {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  background: #FFF;
  width: auto;
}

.second-level-menu>li:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

.top-level-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-level-menu>li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.top-level-menu>.style4 {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.top-level-menu>li:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

.top-level-menu li:hover>ul {
  /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.top-level-menu a {
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #093;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  display: block;
  line-height: auto;
}

.top-level-menu a:hover {
  color: #3F6;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.top-level-menu a {
  color: #093;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div id="topmenu">
  <ul class="top-level-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="style4">//</li>
    <li><a href="#">Eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeee</a>
      <ul class="second-level-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Dddddddd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dddddddddd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dddddddddd</a></li>
      </ul>
      <li class="style4">//</li>
      <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAAAA</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Two long words</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two  very long words</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li class="style4">//</li>
        <li><a href="#">Two long words</a></li>
        <li class="style4">//</li>
        <li><a href="#">two words</a>
          <ul class="second-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#">single</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">single</a></li>
            <li class="style4">//</li>
          </ul>
          <li class="style4">//</li>
          <li><a href="#">Eeeeeee</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a gap between your main menu and second level menu. Because of that your hover effect is no longer exist. To check try this code

```
.top-level-menu > li > a { border: 1px solid blue; }
.second-level-menu { border: 1px solid red; }
```

and to resolve this use

```
.top-level-menu > li > a { padding:8px 0px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Removing `top:30px` from `.second-level-menu` will fix the issue.**

If you want some gap between the main menu and the second level menu. You can give some padding to the first menu option by adding below-given css -

```
.second-level-menu > li:first-child {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```css
.third-level-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

.third-level-menu>li {
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
}

.third-level-menu>li:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

.second-level-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}



.second-level-menu>li {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  background: #FFF;
  width: auto;
}

.second-level-menu>li:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

.top-level-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.top-level-menu>li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.top-level-menu>.style4 {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.top-level-menu>li:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

.top-level-menu li:hover>ul {
  /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.top-level-menu a {
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #093;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  display: block;
  line-height: auto;
}

.top-level-menu a:hover {
  color: #3F6;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.top-level-menu a {
  color: #093;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div id="topmenu">
  <ul class="top-level-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="style4">//</li>
    <li><a href="#">Eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeee</a>
      <ul class="second-level-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Dddddddd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dddddddddd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dddddddddd</a></li>
      </ul>
      <li class="style4">//</li>
      <li><a href="#">AAAAAAAAAA</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Two long words</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two  very long words</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li class="style4">//</li>
        <li><a href="#">Two long words</a></li>
        <li class="style4">//</li>
        <li><a href="#">two words</a>
          <ul class="second-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#">single</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">single</a></li>
            <li class="style4">//</li>
          </ul>
          <li class="style4">//</li>
          <li><a href="#">Eeeeeee</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```